# Sending E-Mail with "temporary" attachment with Java in Android

Tags: java, android, attachment

I wrote an App that should export some data and send them as E-Mail.
Sending E-Mail from Java, using the standard E-Mail-program is not a problem, but I need to attach this file...

Well, attaching the file is not a problem, too, but I have to save the file somewhere... And after sending the E-Mail I have to delete it, too...

I searched for a possibility to give the data for the attachment in other ways (eg: as Stream) but I didn't find a solution...
I tried to find a solution to delete the temporary file after sending the E-Mail, but I had many problem here too, since I can't know **when** the E-Mail-App finished to send the E-Mail...

Can someone help me? The best way for me is to have a Stream an giving it to the Intent and let the E-Mail-App to send the E-Mail, but if it is not possible, I can write the data somewhere on the SD, but I have to know when the E-Mail was sent, in order to delete the file...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Luca